# Raspberry Pi Imager shows blank window on storage

Tags: raspberry-pi-imager

If I click "storage" while using the Raspberry Pi Imager, I only get a blank Window
[image: blank window]

Selecting the OS works fine. The sd card is connected to my pc and recognized

```
Device         Boot  Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mmcblk0p1        8192    532479    524288   256M  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
/dev/mmcblk0p2      532480 249737215 249204736 118.8G 83 Linux
```

Im am using Arch Linux and install the rpi-imager from AUR. There are two packages and I tried both

```
aur/rpi-imager 1.7.5-1 [+72 ~2.31] [Installed: 1.7.4.1-1]
    Raspberry Pi Imaging Utility
aur/rpi-imager-bin 1.7.5-1 [+16 ~0.44]
    Raspberry Pi Imaging Utility
```

Comment: `he sd card is connected to my pc and recoginzed` what is your PC? looks like not Windows, is that correct?

Comment: yes it's an arch linux

Comment: how did you install rpi-imager on arch?

Comment: probably from AUR

Comment: Fair enough ... I guess that's why it's not the current version ... have you tried running it as root?

Comment: I'm having the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like a recent update to the util-linux package on Arch (that includes lsblk) makes it so that some SD cards are no longer flagged as removable. This makes them not selectable from the UI.

There's [already an issue created](https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-imager/issues/606) to address this case.

For now you can try to create the image via the CLI with the *enable-writing-system-drives* flag (which includes "non removable" devices) such as:

```
rpi-imager --cli --debug --enable-writing-system-drives [image file] [SD card device]
```

Comment: Downgrading util-linux with `sudo pacman -U /var/cache/pacman/pkg/util-linux-2.38.1-4-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst` made the gui show the SD card to me

Comment: I simply installed the latest version of the RPI Imager using `rpi-imager-git` AUR package. The issue should be now resolved in version `1.7.6`of RPI Imager

Answer (score 1):

The storage window on the Pi imager shows up as blank only when there is no SD card inserted into the SD Card slot on your laptop or desktop
i.e. it shows as blank when it does not detect a card in the SD card slot

So step 1: Check if your SD card is inserted into your laptop's SD card slot
Step 2: Check if it is inserted properly & being detected in File explorer

If both the above are done you will not see a blank window on clicking the storage button

Beginners might also mistakenly insert the SD card into the Pi device assuming that one can write to the SD card even while it is inserted into the Pi device. This is not the case

Hope this helps.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Edited to include more details